# How to select row with group into 2 specific values by Descending order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select queries a table with group by only 2 value in specific field. Like example bellow.
I have a table that normally having 2 value each minute. But some time having more than 2 value in each minute and I have selected by descending order.
Avoid that, I want to field of minute value `[TimeStamp]` can be group by 2 item based descending order and skip when have more than 2 value.

```
SELECT TOP 10
dbo.ConRadVacuum.[TimeStamp],
dbo.ConRadVacuum.Tag,
dbo.ConRadVacuum.[Value]


FROM
ConRadVacuum
ORDER BY
[TimeStamp] DESC
```

I want "selected row" (32 minute) can be selected only two like the other rows
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include text data, not links, and not pasted images.

Comment: How do you want to select the 2 rows? The image shows values of (TA, 4),  (EG , 5) and (EG, 11) for the timestamp of 3. Which 2 rows would you keep and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `row_number()` function by partitioning over minute part of your timestamp field, something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (
            partition by datepart(minute, cast([TimeStamp] as datetime)) 
                       --^^ I use `datepart()` over cast of your timestamp field 
                       --If your field is `datetime` you don't need to `cast`
            order by [TimeStamp] desc) seq
from t) tt
where seq <= 2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eec7a/1)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question very well, but i think you can put your query in CTE and add ROW_Number to it, then select your cte where your row number field is 1 or 2